# Example of drawing rectangle in picture-mode

Tags: picture-mode

I have been going through the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Picture-Mode.html) of `picture-mode` and have been wondering if it's possible to draw a rectangle and connect it with another rectangle or something like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally managed to draw some rectangles. These were the steps:

- Enable picture mode via `M-x picture-mode`.
- Write the content that you want to place inside each rectangle.
- Draw the rectangles by selecting rectangle regions around each piece of text and running the command `picture-draw-rectangle` (bound to `C-c C-r`).
- Now connect them using commands available in `artist-mode`. Enable artist minor mode via `M-x artist-mode`.
- Now go near one rectangle and run the command `artist-key-set-point` (`RET`) and then continue to your destination rectangle to connect them and press `RET` again.

Sample rectangles drawn using that method:

```
   +------------+           +------------+
   | Rectangle1 |-----------+ Rectangle2 |
   +------------+           +------------+
```

Would be happy to know if there are any other methods.